# Importing private key to X509Certificate2Collection using only X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable

Tags: .net, azure, import, pfx

I am importing a private key from a pfx file using the .NET framework. Specifically I'm using the X509Certificate2Collection.Import Method (String, String, X509KeyStorageFlags) method to do so.

I am only passing in the X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable flag, which works fine for me in dev/test and in production on an Azure website. I.e.

```
X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
collection.Import(PfxFileLocation, Password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

A 3rd party is trying to reuse my assembly. It works fine for them in dev/test. However, when they run it in Azure, they get errors about the certificate file not being found. They asked me to open up the flags, which seemed to work for them. I.e.

```
X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
collection.Import(PfxFileLocation, Password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

I'm trying to understand what's going on. Is it a security risk to open up these flags? Based on the MSDN documentation, I can't understand why this would need to be opened up. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms148499%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Can anyone throw any light on this for me?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late but you need to add X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet

Otherwise you will run in the ssl 1312 error as I did